# Jenkins throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid refspec refs/heads/** Error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to activate a pipeline on any merge request change. This works as long as my pipeline script is in `Jenkins UI`. Now I outsourced my script on `GitLab`, and the checkout should happen via the pipeline via scm option.

But all I get on build (yes, it triggers) is:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid refspec refs/heads/**

This happens if I leave the branch specifier empty, this is because I want to listen to any change. If I specify the branch, the build goes through.

My refspec:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/merge-requests/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/merge-requests/*
```

Comment: Found the Jenkins Issue for this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46588

Comment: @ChrisAnnODell thank you ver much. At least I know now I am not alone with this issue :)

Comment: Nope, not alone.  It got me too which led me to your question :D

Comment: this comment helped me: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46588?focusedCommentId=317526&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-317526

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Most likely this is a Jenkins bug. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46588
There seems to a solution anyway:

In your project configuration under Pipeline -> SCM -> Branches to build -> "Branch Specifier (blank for 'any'):
Do not use blank for any or * or .* or **. Use:

```
*/*
```

Another workaround would be to disable Lightweight Checkout.

PS: 
Big thanks to ChrisAnnODell and Omurbek Kadyrbekov for linking the solutions in first place.
I'm still a bit puzzled that there is no fix for over 2 years now...

Comment: Where should the Jenkinsfile be added? in the workspace of Jenkins UI or our git repo directory?

Comment: @julianjoseph I don't know how your question relates to this. We have the jenkins file in our git repo, but this configuration needs to be done in the jenkins UI.

Comment: 2021, Jenkins v2.3 and this is still an issue, disabling Lightweight Checkout works.